# Is it possible to create T-SQL file containing mixed Arabic (right-to-left) and English?

Tags: t-sql, utf-8, internationalization, arabic, right-to-left

I have a database that caters for English and Arabic, and normally these are separate and cause no issues.  I have a requirement to mix them - and this is not a problem in the database using nvarchar and when the user directly inputs the values.

However, we can't give the user direct access to the DB, so we wanted to write a simple insert script (xxx.sql file) and get them to edit the values...but we are struggling!

In Word, you can change language/text direction fairly simply to get the correct message, but when c&p'd into a sql file (plain text) the direction and/or encoding get messed up :(

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Already using Notepad++, ...the issue is in the change from LTR to RTL on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Let user use any text editor which can produce correct text file. This file should be not sql script but a file with comma separated values. Then you will be able to bulk import these values correctly into any database structure you need.